# Issue overriding __get__ in Python

Tags: python, list, inheritance

I have a class:

```
from collections import UserList


class ItemList(UserList):
    data = []

    def __init__(self, contents):
        self.data = contents

    def __get__(self, index):
        result = list.__get__(self, index)
        if type(result) is list:
            if len(result) > 1:
                return ItemList(result)
        else:
            return result
```

It seems in my case that **get** isn't even being called when I index an instance of the `ItemList` class. What I'm trying to do is return a new instance of `ItemClass` if the result of an index returns more than one item (a list). So I would expect this:

```
>>> il = ItemList(contents)
>>> type(il[1:3])
<class 'ItemList'>
```

But I'm getting this:

```
>>> il = ItemList(contents)
>>> type(il[1:3])
<class 'list'>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham the [`UserList`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/collections.html#collections.UserList) class from the standard library I assume.

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't specify. Edited to provide clarity.

Comment: It's `__getitem__` and not `__get__` you want to override.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something more like the following:

```
class ItemList(UserList):
    data = []
    def __init__(self, contents):
        super().__init__()
        self.data = contents
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        result = UserList.__getitem__(self, item)
        if type(result) is list:
            if len(result) > 1:
                return ItemList(result)
        else:
            return result
```